# Raspbian can't forward port to a ip in lan

Tags: raspbian, networking, ethernet, vpn, iptables

I have a problem: I have a DVR connected to my router and I want to access it from remote but in my country there aren't ISP that offers free ports. So I bought a Raspberry Pi, connected it to Hamachi and I setup it to connect to my private network. Now I want that when I try to connect to my Raspberry Pi on Hamachi 25.79.239.251:123 it redirects me to its internal lan ip 192.168.0.100:34567.

I tried this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/532569/how-to-do-port-forwarding-redirecting-on-debian) but it didn't work.

Comment: Hello and welcome to RPi.SE If you tried anything yet feel free to post details and/or error messages to provide better help.